# How to expand $\langle \textbf{x}-\textbf{y},\textbf{x}-\textbf{y}\rangle$ using the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, matrix-norms

### The Question

> \begin{align}||\textbf{x}+\textbf{y}||^2+||\textbf{x}-\textbf{y}||^2&=\langle\textbf{x}+\textbf{y},\textbf{x}+\textbf{y} \rangle+\langle\textbf{x}-\textbf{y},\textbf{x}-\textbf{y} \rangle\\&=\langle\textbf{x},\textbf{x}+\textbf{y}\rangle+\langle\textbf{y},\textbf{x}+\textbf{y}\rangle+\langle\textbf{x},\textbf{x}-\textbf{y}\rangle-\langle\textbf{y},\textbf{x}-\textbf{y}\rangle\\&=\langle\textbf{x},\textbf{x}\rangle+\langle\textbf{x},\textbf{y}\rangle+\langle\textbf{y},\textbf{x}\rangle+\langle\textbf{y},\textbf{y}\rangle+\langle\textbf{x},\textbf{x}\rangle-\langle\textbf{x},\textbf{y}\rangle-\langle\textbf{y},\textbf{x}\rangle+\langle\textbf{y},\textbf{y}\rangle\\&=2\langle\textbf{x},\textbf{x}\rangle+2\langle\textbf{y},\textbf{y}\rangle\\&=2||\textbf{x}||^2+2||\textbf{y}||^2\end{align}

### My Understanding

I understood how $\langle \textbf{x}+\textbf{y},\textbf{x}+\textbf{y}\rangle$ was expanded. I believe you take the $\textbf{x}$'s from each side and make them into a vector. Then the $\textbf{y}$'s. And then the $\textbf{x}$ from the first vector and $\textbf{y}$ from the second. And lastly the $\textbf{y}$ from the first vector and $x$ from the second. I repeated this same process for $\langle \textbf{x}-\textbf{y},\textbf{x}-\textbf{y}\rangle$ and got: $\langle \textbf{x},\textbf{x}\rangle+\langle -\textbf{y},-\textbf{y}\rangle+\langle \textbf{x},-\textbf{y}\rangle+\langle -\textbf{y},\textbf{x}\rangle$. How did they get a negative in front of the $\textbf{x}$? Also, why does $\langle -\textbf{y},-\textbf{y}\rangle$ become $\langle \textbf{y},\textbf{y}\rangle$?

Comment: $<\cdot, \cdot>$ is linear in each variable

Comment: Inner products are linear in their first coordinate by definition, so $\langle (-1)y, x \rangle = (-1)\langle y, x \rangle$ by the axioms. Conjugate symmetry gives you something similar in the second coordinate: $\langle x, (-1)y \rangle = \overline{-1} \cdot \langle x, y \rangle = -\langle x, y \rangle$.

Comment: Little correction to @TheoBendit's comment: We might have conjugate linearity in the first argument, but that does not matter, as the addittivity is true for both of the arguments with both of the definitions.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to two properties of the dot product:

1. linearity in the first argument $\langle\alpha{x} + \beta{y},z\rangle=\alpha\langle{x}, z\rangle+\beta\langle{y}, z\rangle$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are complex numbers, $x$, $y$ and $z$ are vectors;
2. $\langle x, y\rangle=\langle y, x\rangle^{*}$, where the symbol $*$ is a complex conjugation.

So, $\langle x, \alpha y + \beta z\rangle=\langle \alpha y + \beta z, x\rangle^{*} = \alpha^{*}\langle y, x\rangle^{*} + \beta^{*}\langle z, x\rangle^{*} = \alpha^{*}\langle x, y\rangle + \beta^{*}\langle x, z\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

The Cauchy–Schwarz inequality is used to prove that the inner product is a continuous function with respect to the topology induced by the inner product itself. Therefore, using the dot product, the following hold for any vectors $\textbf{x}, \textbf{y}$, and $\textbf{z}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and scalars $c \in \mathbb{R}$

1. $\textbf{x}\cdot\textbf{y}=\textbf{y}\cdot\textbf{x}.$
2. $\textbf{x}\cdot\textbf{x}=||\textbf{x}||^2.$
3. $\textbf{x}\cdot(\textbf{y}+\textbf{z})=\textbf{x}\cdot\textbf{y}+\textbf{x}\cdot\textbf{z}$ and $(\textbf{x}+\textbf{y})\cdot\textbf{z}=\textbf{x}\cdot\textbf{z}+\textbf{y}\cdot\textbf{z}.$
4. $(c\textbf{x})\cdot\textbf{y}=\textbf{x}\cdot c\textbf{y}=c(\textbf{x}\cdot\textbf{y}).$